# Kubectl commands only working with minikube

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, k3d

How come that when I use minikube, all my `kubectl` commands work properly e.g. `kubectl get nodes`. But the moment I **stop** minikube and try using k3d.

1. Install k3d with `choco install k3d`
2. Make a cluster in k3d
3. Set the context to the created cluster

Somehow commands like `kubectl get nodes` and `kubectl get pods` don't work and return

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 145.93.104.168:61199: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or e
stablished connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Why can't I run the kubectl commands properly with k3d?

Kubectl config view:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://host.docker.internal:61199
  name: k3d-kwetter-cluster
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: C:\Users\ZRC\.minikube\ca.crt
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Thu, 07 Apr 2022 11:25:37 CEST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.25.2
      name: cluster_info
    server: https://127.0.0.1:65229
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: k3d-kwetter-cluster
    user: admin@k3d-kwetter-cluster
  name: k3d-kwetter-cluster
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    extensions:
    - extension:
        last-update: Thu, 07 Apr 2022 11:25:37 CEST
        provider: minikube.sigs.k8s.io
        version: v1.25.2
      name: context_info
    namespace: default
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: k3d-kwetter-cluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: admin@k3d-kwetter-cluster
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: C:\Users\ZRC\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.crt
    client-key: C:\Users\ZRC\.minikube\profiles\minikube\client.key
```

Extra context: I tried to not use minikube because I couldn't externally access my deployed application at all (NodePort, with ingress, port forwarding...I tried a lot of things, but those just didn't work. But now k3d isn't working either)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Docker Desktop, go to settings > Kubernetes > Enable Kuberenetes set to true.